# Magento 2 huge number of new user registrations

Tags: magento2

My online store receives a huge number of new users creation (over 500 new users per 30 seconds)

So, I enabled captcha for new accounts, the new accounts creation have stopped but I get thousands of new captcha verification images in

> /pub/media/captcha/base

more than 113000 new image whithin 2 houres

I passed my DNS through Cloudflare and marked visitors from China, India, Russia (the source countries of the attack), they must pass the Cloudflare challenge before accessing the site, but I still receive a new account creation attempts from Hong Kong for exemple

but in case I activate the mode "under attack", it stops all those attempts but all store visitors are invited to wait 5 seconds before accessing the store (Cloudflare)

I am using Magento 2.2.5

Comment: I had the same issue. I resolved it by creating an observer event when customer is created and log the source details, after that I blocked those from htaccess.

Comment: the problem is that if I authorize the creation of new clients, I will get thousands of fake users; and it does not make sense if I block them after

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by passing my DNS through Cloudflare and blacklisting some countries source of those attacks.